# How to show a modal view upon a click of a textfield but without the keyboard appearing?

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am a newbie to `AngularJS` and `Ionic` framework.

I'm building a hybrid app using `PhoneGap` and Ionic.

I have a situation where the user clicks on a UITextField, and then a modal pops up with a list of account numbers where selecting an account number will make the modal go away and the selected value entered in the UITextField.

So far I have made it to a stage where clicking on the UITextField fires the modal popup event, but since the input type is text, the keyboard shows up too. (iOS platform)

How can I go about this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try to disable the TextField as the data will be coming from the modal screen. This will prevent the user from entering any data and for the keyboard to disable as well. I have done a similar thing using other framework and it works without any issues. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

use `UITextFieldDelegate` method `textFieldDidBeginEditing`

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Hi @raki, I'm using PhoneGap + Ionic to develop this app. Is this still possible in that case? No right?

Comment: don't PhoneGap have UITextFieldDelegate's ?,actually i don't know about PhoneGap..

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, if u need any more information then u can share.

```
  -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
 {
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
   SampleViewController *sample = [[SampleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SampleViewController" bundle:nil];
   [self.navigationController presentViewController:sample animated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```